# How can I find search results that are relevant to my recent web history?

Tags: google-search

Is there any way to find Google Search results that are relevant to recent browsing history? I want to find search results that are relevant to my recent browsing history (since it might be useful for navigation purposes.)

There might be some way to find search terms that are relevant to a specific URL, I'm not sure about finding pages that are relevant to multiple URLs. Essentially, what I'm asking is whether it's possible to obtain a list of relevant search results, given a list of URLs.

There's a browser extension called SimilarWeb that finds pages that are relevant to the current page, but I don't know of any software that uses all recent search history to find relevant results.